# How to access data sent by AJAX to a PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-droppable

I have this droppable Jquery along with two pieces of data I want to send to a PHP file when the object gets dropped:

```
 $( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
         var playerid = ui.draggable[0].getAttribute("data-playerid");
         var value = jQuery(this).data('value');
          console.log(playerid);
          console.log(value);
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: "ajax-update-value.php",
            data: {playerid:playerid, value:value},
            success: function(result) {
            // do something with the result of the AJAX call here
                alert(result);
            }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

And in the PHP file, I want to use those two specific values to update my MySQL database. I have this below, but it's not pulling in the values, so I'm obviously doing something wrong/stupid.
What is the proper way to access the two pieces of data?

```
$playerid=$_POST['playerid'];
$value=$_POST['value'];
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Check your browser's devtools network tab - does the POST actually happen?  If so, what is the payload?  And how does your backend respond?  Have you tried doing eg `print_r($_POST);` to see what you're getting?  Is the output of your `console.log()`s as you expect?

Comment: Change the line `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` to `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",` and see what happens

Comment: @DarkBee They're not sending JSON, so that's irrelevant. They would have to use `data: JSON.stringify({playerid:playerid, value:value}),`

Comment: @KenLee Or just remove the `contentType` option entirely. The default is URL-encoded.

Comment: @Don'tPanic devtools network tab does say that POST request method was successful (green dot and 200 OK next to "status code").  I also did print_r($_POST) and it comes back with an empty array, i.e."Array ()"

The values are definitely in the two variables on the page because I console.log them after they are set but before AJAX does it's thing and the two numbers appear correctly but they for some reason aren't getting to the PHP page